# check difference after pull

Tags: git, github

**After** I have pulled from origin master branch(`git pull origin master`), how can I check the code difference between the version before pulled and the current version(after pulled)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to run

```
git fetch
```

instead of `pull`.  Then you'll have your `master` and `origin/master` both available locally, and you can just diff the two before pulling.

Otherwise, if you've already run `pull`, use

```
git reflog
```

to find the previous HEAD commit on your local `master`, and compare that to the current HEAD.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `pull`, use

```
git fetch origin
git diff ..origin
```

and then

```
git merge origin
```

or

```
git rebase origin
```

Alternatively, you can, before the `pull`, use `git log -1` to get the current revision (something like `commit 41db5abc53351184cbb56a796e6c5e81de73f125`) and then after the `git pull`, do

```
git diff 41db5abc..
```